# how to render multiple languages in AngularJS webpage?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, I've a requirement where I should display the products of different countries in a single webpage with different languages(localized language of that countries). Response is coming in the single JSON file for all the countries.

I've tried to use Angular Translate but I was not successful. Could anyone suggest if there is any better way to do?

Comment: What kind of problems did you have with angular-translate? I'm using it an application of mine and it works fine.

Comment: You could use a provider (which is a Service). He's prupose is configurate other Services (service and factory)

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular Translate with Multi-language support and it's working fine,
You can check this [link](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/ ?

we have implemented it by creating different `js` as per language